# powershell get-content need IF

Tags: powershell

```
    while($true)
{
  Get-Content C:\Steam\steamapps\startup\server_console_*.log -wait | where {$_ -match "Game finished."} |
  foreach { 
     Start-Sleep -s 30
     restart-computer -Force

  }
}
```

Hi!
I would like to have system reboot when "Game finished." is listed twice the the log, how can i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($true)
{
  if ((Get-Content C:\Steam\steamapps\startup\server_console_*.log | where {$_ -match "Game finished"}).Count -gt 1)
  {
    restart-Computer -force
  }
  start-sleep -seconds 30
}
```

In my opinion it would be better to not have a while $true loop in PS, but to have a simple `if (..) {restart-Computer}` and schedule (scheduled tasks) that script to run every minute, 5 minute etc. This will be much less resource hungry:

```
if ((Get-Content C:\Steam\steamapps\startup\server_console_*.log | where {$_ -match "Game finished"}).Count -gt 1)
  {
    restart-Computer -force
  }
```

Comment: the powershell exe using 1.5 gb ram when the scrip is running after few hours any way to only check new lines?

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: its scans a live log from game server and when game writes "value" i want to restart the server

Comment: @AntonRyzantsev Get-Content TextFile -Tail 10 gets the last 10 Lines. But when you want to know which lines are new you have to compare two files(-states) and check what changed.